# ASP.NET and IIS 7 - unexpected URL in IE10 after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-10

I'm migrating one of our website to new server, running Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.

Web is perfectly running under Google Chrome, but there is something weird while using IE 10.

Example in Google Chrome (which is OK):

1. Entering www.ourweb.com/Login.aspx
2. Logging in
3. Redirected to www.ourweb.com/Home.aspx

Example in IE 10:

1. Entering www.ourweb.com/Login.aspx
2. Logging in
3. Redirected to www.ourweb.com/**(F(UTq2wZuGLRl0BKou8K0HshpBua96yAkY81e7lJOeUvuhO5Njmsh1cHhPeiJkO7tnPBj7xxUI6zy1XVkX_BfV5vMJiKlNz76kd1dWBqk0yXrIx67baSOFVxVnMQ4o6v3h2NctEVwuGAGVRvsrf8dAcaFXLuu-iPNw9aJrUtxgJJgfrqtWQvuT24v8vCmVu36A0))**/Home.aspx

Have you ever seen this behaviour? I really don't know what causes this set of letters in URL.

Comment: It seems like, session id is included in the url. I am not sure this is session id. Check the Web.config file

Comment: It happened the same to me: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explorer is using cookieless sessions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

It is a bug with IE10 headers not handling cookies properly

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/662275/asp-net-user-agent-sniffing-and-ie10-internet-explorer-10

Suggested Workaround is:

Add the file `~\App_Browsers\BrowserFile.browser` with the following:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
        <capabilities><!-- To avoid wrong detections of e.g. IE10 -->
            <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
            <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

Anyway there is an hotfix for this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

maybe your server is not updated...